# How to return the lowest 8 values in a table of scores in sql

Tags: sql-server

i have the following sql table 'S3results':

```
+-----------+----------+------------------+-------+
| Studentno | Fullname |     Subject      | Fmagg |
+-----------+----------+------------------+-------+
|    100509 | Terry    | Accounts         |     1 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Art              |     6 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Biology          |     3 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Chemistry        |     2 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Commerce         |     2 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Computer Studies |     4 |
|    100509 | Terry    | English          |     6 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Geography        |     1 |
|    100509 | Terry    | History          |     1 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Mathematics      |     3 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Physics          |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Accounts         |     4 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Art              |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Biology          |     5 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Chemistry        |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Commerce         |     3 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Computer Studies |     3 |
|    100510 | Sena     | English          |     4 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Geography        |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | History          |     4 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Mathematics      |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Physics          |     2 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Accounts         |     2 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Art              |     1 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Biology          |     2 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Chemistry        |     1 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Commerce         |     5 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Computer Studies |     3 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | English          |     6 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Geography        |     1 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | History          |     1 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Mathematics      |     2 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Physics          |     6 |
+-----------+----------+------------------+-------+
```

what i want is to select 8 subjects with the lowest scores for each student in the fmagg column but mathematics and english should be included in the results irrespective of their score.

below is the result i want:

```
+-----------+----------+------------------+-------+
| Studentno | Fullname |     Subject      | Fmagg |
+-----------+----------+------------------+-------+
|    100509 | Terry    | Accounts         |     1 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Geography        |     1 |
|    100509 | Terry    | History          |     1 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Physics          |     1 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Chemistry        |     2 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Commerce         |     2 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Mathematics      |     3 |
|    100509 | Terry    | English          |     6 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Art              |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Chemistry        |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Geography        |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Mathematics      |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Physics          |     2 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Commerce         |     3 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Computer Studies |     3 |
|    100510 | Sena     | English          |     4 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Art              |     1 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Chemistry        |     1 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Geography        |     1 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | History          |     1 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Accounts         |     2 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Biology          |     2 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Mathematics      |     2 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | English          |     6 |
+-----------+----------+------------------+-------+
```

getting the top 8 almost worked for me using the code below but it was not what i wanted

```
select StudentNo,FullName ,FMagg,Subject   from S3Results  where FMagg in (select distinct top 8 FMagg  from S3Results where Subject ='Mathematics' or (select distinct top 8 FMagg  from S3Results where Subject ='Mathematics' or Subject ='English' order by FMagg desc)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using the ROW_NUMBER Window function in combination with a common-table-expresssion (cte). This works - maybe it's not perfect but at least it delivers the desired output:

```
;WITH cte AS
(SELECT Studentno, Fullname, [Subject], Fmagg,  
        CASE WHEN [Subject] IN ('Mathematics','English')
            THEN 0
            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Studentno ORDER BY Fmagg ASC)
        END AS Ranking
FROM    S3Results)

SELECT  Studentno, Fullname, [Subject], Fmagg 
FROM    cte
WHERE   Ranking < 8
ORDER BY Studentno,Fmagg
```

Above code will always deliver 8 rows (or less if you don't have 8 lines in your base table) for each student. So you have to decide: 
If you want always want 8 lines per student you're good with `ROW_NUMBER`. If you want the 6 weakest scores plus mathematics and english you should take a look at replacing `ROW_NUMBER` with `DENSE_RANK`. Then you probably get 9 or more rows per student. Take a look at this and you will understand the difference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-at/library/ms189798.aspx

Comment: Sorry i have been away for a while, the above code worked for me until i realized that it's excluding values equal to or greater than 5 unless it's English. for example given a student scored the following: 5,2,3,5,2,3,3,4,7,7,1 running that query will produce: 3,1,2,2,3,3,4. as you can see those are 7rows and not 8 as i wanted. thanks in advance.